# System.runAs() does not function as expected

Tags: code-coverage, test-setup

```
    static testMethod void testForDeletePrevent(){
    PCA_Settings__c pcaConfig = TestDataFactory.createPcaSettings();
    Common_Settings__c config = TestDataFactory.createCommonSettings();
    
    Account testInd = TestDataFactory.createTestIndividual(config);
    insert testInd;
    
    Case testCase = TestDataFactory.createTestCase();
    testCase.AccountId = testInd.Id;
    insert testCase;
    
    User testUser = TestDataFactory.createTestUser();
    config.Cannot_Delete_Cases_Roles__c = userInfo.getUserRoleId();
    update config;
    testUser.UserRoleId = config.Cannot_Delete_Cases_Roles__c;
    System.runAs(testUser) {
        
        Test.startTest();
        Database.DeleteResult result = Database.delete(testCase, false);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertEquals(testCase.IsDeleted, false); //evaluates as true
        System.assertEquals(config.Cannot_Delete_Cases_Roles__c, testUser.UserRoleId);
        System.assertEquals(result.getId(), testCase.Id);
        System.assertEquals(result.isSuccess(), false); //evaluates as false
        System.assert(result.getErrors().size() > 0);
        System.assertEquals('You cannot delete this record. Please contact your supervisor or administrator for assistance', result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
}
```

In this code, the portion within the System.runAs(testUser) section is expected to be executed by testUser. However, when a debug log is set up to read userInfo.getUserName() and userInfo.getUserRoleId(), the current user is being returned as the user running the test and not as testUser. Is this the expected result, or is something else going on?

Comment: There are definite issues around `System.runAs`, though I have only seen it in relation to async processing (such as [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddLNUAZ/ensure-that-the-runas-user-applies-when-running-a-batch-in-a-test)).

Comment: where did you insert the debug statement in the above code?  Your observed behavior is not expected and at variance with my experience

Comment: The debug statements were inserted immediately after `Test.startTest();` . I was using `System.debug('Current User: ' + userInfo.getUserName())` and `System.debug('Current User: ' + userInfo.getUserRoleId())`. Then compared those with `System.debug('Test User: ' + testUser.Name)` and `System.debug('Test User: ' + testUser.UserRoleId)`. I was getting different results for both debug statement sets.